# Debug Multiple ASP.Net Projects in VisualStudio2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, model-view-controller, visual-studio-debugging

I have a solution file with two applications loaded. Both are MVC enabled apps, one is a data API the other is a service that consumes the API. I dont have a server to house this application on yet and would like to debug them both in Visual Studio 2010, it appears that this is not a unique request, and is completely possible via this answer: [How to run/debug multiple web application projects with-in the same solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216943/how-to-run-debug-multiple-web-application-projects-with-in-the-same-solution)

[image: Project Overview]

however converting the site to a web application did not allow me to achieve debugging both projects at once. I cant even get the web-ports to align. Is this an instance where I will be *forced* into using a local IIS installation just for debugging purposes? or is the asp.net express server sufficient and I have not found the correct resource for setting up my applications?

[image: Project Settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need both sites to be available on same URL you have two options:

1. Use external server to host sites instead of using integrated server (any big reason you can't install IIS on your dev machine?)
2. Create 3rd project as parent of those two and add files belonging to those projects into third one. You don't need to remove other two projects or any files from them. Just make sure that you are not simply creating a copy of files, but referencing same ones.

Comment: if these are both integrated into a single solution, how will a third solution solve this issue? cthulu is a child of searchportal, and is not integrating into the express server.

Comment: Please clarify your problem. You cant have two sites hosted in Cassini (VS integrated) web server. Third project (not solution as you said) would solve the problem by containing all pages of both projects and then debugging that third project would allow you to debug all of the code. Still, why not publish sites into IIS on your developer machine and debug there?

Comment: I ended up using IIS Express (part of the WebMatrix packaging) It's fitting the bill well enough. I suppose you have to be willing to give and take with the whole MS suite of dev tools.

Comment: IIS express comes with Windows at least from XP onwards. Check "Turn Windows features on or off" in Windows 7 or corresponding place in previous versions of Windows. I'm quite happy with such dev tools, but I guess it's subjective.